# Way in hibernate to alter boolean value of column

Tags: java, hibernate

How can i write similar to below query in hibernate

> `update tb_image set active = !active;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used native Query, as there is no way to right same query using Hibernate Query Language.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a native query for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1. A separate property for the reversed value and map that property in Hibernate
2. [Entity Listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) and their @PrePersist

First option looks easier and it would be easier to understand it, imo.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is that you would already have the entity you need to update loaded, then just set the field as usual. `setBool(!isBool())` then commit the change to the DB. I'm concerned about your design when you need to operate on the data in the persistent store instead of operating on the objects directly.